# Get the index of the next non-zero value in a list in python

Tags: python

Suppose you have a list `[1,2,3,4,5,0,0,0,7,8, ...]`. Given a current index, what would be the best way to get the next non-zero index? For example, if index is 2, then the next non-zero one is 3; if 4, then 8.

Comment: Depends. If you have a large list that does not change and need to do this lookup a lot, then the most efficient way would probably be to store the indices of zeroes in a separate set and then compare againts that. If it's a small list or if the content changes, then you simple iterate forward from the given index and check the list at index+x until the value is non-zero.

Comment: @Melchia Yes, so?

Comment: @MikeScotty Good point.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,0,0,0,7,8]

def nextZeroIndex(array, start):
    nextItems = array[start+1:]
    for i, x in enumerate(nextItems):
        if x != 0:
            return 1 + start + i

print(nextZeroIndex(a, 2)) # 3
print(nextZeroIndex(a, 5)) # 8
print(nextZeroIndex(a, 4)) # 8
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def get_next_index(lst, index):
    try:
        return next(i + index + 1 for i, n in enumerate(lst[index + 1:]) if n != 0)
    except StopIteration:
        return None

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 7, 8]
get_next_index(lst, 2)  # 3
get_next_index(lst, 9)  # None
get_next_index(lst, 100)  # None
```

Iterate over the list starting from the specified index until you find a number different from zero, if the index is out of bounds or a non-zero is found return `None`

Answer (score 0):

you could also achieve this using itertools:

```
from itertools import compress,count
start = 4
next = list(compress(count(),l[start+1:]))[0]+start+1
print(next)

output:

8
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have a class where all the "valid" indices (non-zero value) are stored and when you want to find the next index for a non-zero value starting from a given index, you just search for the next valid index which is greater than your starting index

```
from bisect import bisect_right

class NextIndexNonZero:
    def __init__(self, your_numbers: list):

        # filter out the indices for zero values/numbers
        valid_indices = filter(lambda x: x[1] != 0, enumerate(your_numbers))
        self.valid_indices = list(map(lambda x: x[0], valid_indices))

        self.max_index = self.valid_indices[-1]


    def find(self, start_index: int) -> int:

        if start_index >= self.max_index:
            return f'There is no index non-zero greater than {start_index}'

        next_index = bisect_right(self.valid_indices, start_index)
        return self.valid_indices[next_index]

a = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ]
n = NextIndexNonZero(a)
print(n.find(2))
print(n.find(4))
```

output:

```
4
There is no index non-zero greater than 4
```